# How to count the characters of a string and assign them to different groups (lower case & upper case) in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, uppercase, lowercase

I wrote a program in C that  gets a string from the user (50 characters is the limit) and assign the upper-case characters to a string named `upper`, and the lower-case characters to `lower`, in the end it supposed to prints those strings (the `upper` first). My problem is when I enter a string, it only prints one string (i.e if the string starts with an upper character then `upper` will be printed) instead of two of them.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LEN 50

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char upper[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char lower[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] > 'A' && str[i] < 'Z')
        {
            upper[j] = str[i];
        }
        else if (str[i] > 'a' && str[i] < 'z')
        {
            lower[j] = str[i];
        }
        j++;
    }

    printf("%s", upper);
    printf("%s", lower);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using the same index variable j for lower and upper variable. Use different variables for both.

Comment: Also `> 'A'` --> `>= 'A'`

Comment: [ctype.h provides isupper and islower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification#Overview_of_functions) which take into account the current locale.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes the limits are also not correct for the if else.

Comment: You also don't need `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` because `fgets()` will insert a NULL and your declaration of `str[]`fills it completely with NULLs.

Comment: And when debugging string issues, it helps to bracket the string when printing so you can see if the array of chars is empty. Something like this: `printf("\nUPPER:[%s] LOWER[%s]\n", upper,lower);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use one counter for two arrays. You increment the counter, no matter which array you fill in. As a result, the first letter to be processed will determine which array will *not* have its first character as the C string NULL terminator.

So? So, when you use `printf()`, it will stop printing when you use `%s`, as soon as it meets a NULL terminator, as all the functions of `<stdio.h>` do. BTW, you had forgotten to include that library.

One solution would be to use two counters, one for every array and increment the counter of the array that we just filled in.

Moreover, use `>=` instead of `>` to take into account 'a' too. Likewise for 'z', and their capitals.

Putting them all together you get something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h> // you hadn't include that!

#define MAX_LEN 50

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char upper[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char lower[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0; // counter for 'upper'
    int k = 0; // counter for 'lower'

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') // use the equal operator as well for reading 'A' and 'Z' as well
        {
            upper[j++] = str[i]; // increment the counter 'j'
        }
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') // use the equal operator as well for reading 'a' and 'z' as well
        {
            lower[k++] = str[i]; // increment the counter 'k'
        }
    }

    // print your strings, but use a newline for aesthetics
    printf("%s\n", upper);
    printf("%s\n", lower);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Enter a string: Samaras
S
amaras
```

Answer (score 3):

Use different index variables for `upper` and `lower` and in your `if-statements`, change `>` operator to `>=` and similarly `<` to `<=`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LEN 50

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char upper[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char lower[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    int up = 0, low = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            upper[up] = str[i];
            up++;
        }
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            lower[low] = str[i];
            low++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", upper);

    printf("%s", lower);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using j as an iterator for both of your arrays. You don't do that. If you do that, you could have a '\0' at the first place of your other array and it won't be written.

so you should do that:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define MAX_LEN 50

    int main()
    {
        char str[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
        char upper[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
        char lower[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0, h = 0;

        printf("Enter a string: ");
        fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                upper[j++] = str[i];
            }
            else if (str[i] > 'a' && str[i] < 'z')
            {
                lower[h++] = str[i];
            }
        }

        printf("%s", upper);
        printf("%s", lower);

        return 0;
    }
```

Here you are itering on your arrays only when you add one value.
Also as said in comments, you should do `str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'` not `str[i] > 'A' && str[i] < 'Z'`